# What is"error: the following arguments are required"?

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

When Iam running a github project(ID-disentanglement) in Anaconda IDE, I am getting an error like this, can you explain how to resolve this error?

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
usage: main.py [-h] [--gpu GPU] [--face_detection] [--resolution {256,1024}]
               [--load_checkpoint LOAD_CHECKPOINT] --pretrained_models_path
               PRETRAINED_MODELS_PATH [--const_noise | --no_const_noise]
               [--batch_size BATCH_SIZE] [--reals]
               [--test_real_attr | --no_test_real_attr]
               [--results_dir RESULTS_DIR] [--log_debug] [--debug]
               [--dataset_path DATASET_PATH] [--num_epochs NUM_EPOCHS]
               [--cross_frequency CROSS_FREQUENCY] [--unified]
               [--train_real_attr | --no_train_real_attr]
               [--train_data_size TRAIN_DATA_SIZE] [--id_loss | --no_id_loss]
               [--landmarks_loss | --no_landmarks_loss]
               [--pixel_loss | --no_pixel_loss] [--W_D_loss | --no_W_D_loss]
               [--gp | --no_gp] [--pixel_mask_type {uniform,gaussian}]
               [--pixel_loss_type {L1,mix}] [--test_frequency TEST_FREQUENCY]
               [--test_size TEST_SIZE] [--not_improved_exit NOT_IMPROVED_EXIT]
               [--test_with_arcface | --no_test_with_arcface]
               name
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: name
```

arglib.py is imported in main.py, so I think the problem may come from arglib.py. And there is a class from arglib.py and its function that I think which cause this problem(my assumption may not be right).

```
    class BaseArgs(ABC):
        @abstractmethod
        def add_args(self):
            # Hardware
            self.parser.add_argument('--gpu', type=str, default='0')
    
            # Model
            self.parser.add_argument('--face_detection', action='store_true')
            self.parser.add_argument('--resolution', type=int, default=256, choices=[256, 1024])
            self.parser.add_argument('--load_checkpoint')
            self.parser.add_argument('--pretrained_models_path', type=Path, required=True)

            BaseArgs.add_bool_arg(self.parser, 'const_noise')

            # Data
            self.parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=6)
            self.parser.add_argument('--reals', action='store_true', help='Use real inputs')
            BaseArgs.add_bool_arg(self.parser, 'test_real_attr')

            # Log & Results
            self.parser.add_argument('name', type=str, help='Name under which run will be saved')
            self.parser.add_argument('--results_dir', type=str, default='../results')
            self.parser.add_argument('--log_debug', action='store_true')
    
            # Other
            self.parser.add_argument('--debug', action='store_true')
```

And I asked chatGPT, and it said "name: Requires the user to provide a name under which the run will be saved. For example, my_experiment_name." I also searched for solution, they said I should add name in "Run/Debug configuration".
I've tried this name(my_experiment_name), as well as other names like the file's name or folder's name, but no matter what, it always result in an error:"main.py: error: unrecognized arguments:".
My question is, should I try a different name? Or is the problem not really about the name at all?

[And there is the picture of how I set up my parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrF7o.png)

Comment: Can you add a link to the file you're running?

Comment: re: Jeppe: https://github.com/Fatemejamalii/ID-disentanglement

Comment: You need to add an argument when running it. In terminal, you would do `python main.py somenamehere`. If your IDE has a run configuration, it should be possible to set the parameters there.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your reply. But can I achieve the same effect by editing the code itself, or by changing parameters in 'run/debug configuration'?

Comment: The code probably uses the name internally, so if you remove the parameter, you must remove the places it is used (or replace it with the name you want). Best is probably to add a name parameter to 'run/debug configuration' as you mention.

Comment: Yes, I have indeed tried this, but there is an error message:"main.py: error: unrecognized arguments: try_this_name"

Comment: Can you add a picture of what the run configuration looks like?

Comment: Sure! I've edited the question, I added the picture in the last line. And I am very grateful for your patience.

Comment: You have both "name" and "try_this_name" - remove one of them, and then that parameter should be used as the name within the program. :)

Comment: It seems that the question is solved. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Awesome, I have posted an answer. Feel free to accept it if you think it answers the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when using the `argparse.ArgumentParser()`, errors or help-information will be displayed in the format you wrote:

```
usage: main.py [-h] [--gpu GPU] [--face_detection] [--resolution {256,1024}]
               [--load_checkpoint LOAD_CHECKPOINT] --pretrained_models_path
               PRETRAINED_MODELS_PATH [--const_noise | --no_const_noise]
               [--batch_size BATCH_SIZE] [--reals]
               [--test_real_attr | --no_test_real_attr]
               [--results_dir RESULTS_DIR] [--log_debug] [--debug]
               [--dataset_path DATASET_PATH] [--num_epochs NUM_EPOCHS]
               [--cross_frequency CROSS_FREQUENCY] [--unified]
               [--train_real_attr | --no_train_real_attr]
               [--train_data_size TRAIN_DATA_SIZE] [--id_loss | --no_id_loss]
               [--landmarks_loss | --no_landmarks_loss]
               [--pixel_loss | --no_pixel_loss] [--W_D_loss | --no_W_D_loss]
               [--gp | --no_gp] [--pixel_mask_type {uniform,gaussian}]
               [--pixel_loss_type {L1,mix}] [--test_frequency TEST_FREQUENCY]
               [--test_size TEST_SIZE] [--not_improved_exit NOT_IMPROVED_EXIT]
               [--test_with_arcface | --no_test_with_arcface]
               name
```

What this shows, is that running the script should be done as:

```
python main.py [optional arguments here] name

e.g.
python main.py my_special_name
python main.py --batch_size 25 my_special_name
python main.py --batch_size 25 --reals my_special_name
...
```

Most IDE's allows you to set up a run or debug configuration, for which script to run and which arguments to pass.

`argparse.ArgumentParser()` is an easy to use built-in class for managing arguments in Python - you could also just use `sys.argv` directly, which will contain a list of arguments passed to the program.